# Using NDEigensystem to solve the Mathieu equation

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method, eigenvalues

To be able to apply the differential equation capabilities of Mathematica to my graduate thesis, I am trying to apply NDEigensystem to an eigenproblem whose solution I know, but I am having some trouble doing so.

As a test problem, I am using an [algebraic version of the Mathieu equation](https://dlmf.nist.gov/28.2.E3),

$$(1-\zeta^{2})w^{\prime\prime}-\zeta w^{\prime}+\left(a+2q-4q\zeta^{2}\right)w=0$$

For this example I set $q=4/3$ and take only the first three eigenpairs:

```
m = 3; q = 4/3;
op = -(1 - ζ^2) u''[ζ] + ζ u'[ζ] + 2 q (2 ζ^2 - 1) u[ζ];
bc = DirichletCondition[u[ζ] == 0, True];
{λ, fl} = NDEigensystem[{op, bc}, u, {ζ, 0, 1}, m];
```

I chose the Mathieu equation as a nontrivial example as Mathematica already has a function for its evaluation:

```
λt = Table[MathieuCharacteristicB[2 k, q], {k, m}];
flt = Table[With[{k = k, q = q},
MathieuS[MathieuCharacteristicB[2 k, q], q, ArcCos[#]] &], {k, m}];
```

The problem is, I do not get the expected eigenvalues!

```
λ
(* {4.0708, 17.3259, 39.1877} *)
N[λt]
(* {3.85298, 16.0581, 36.0254} *)
```

And of course, plotting shows that the eigenequation is not satisfied at all:

```
With[{u = fl[[1]], b = λ[[1]]},
     Plot[(1 - ζ^2) u''[ζ] - ζ u'[ζ] + (b + 2 q - 4 q ζ^2) u[ζ], {ζ, 0, 1}]]
With[{u = flt[[1]], b = λt[[1]]},
     Plot[(1 - ζ^2) u''[ζ] - ζ u'[ζ] + (b + 2 q - 4 q ζ^2) u[ζ], {ζ, 0, 1}]]
```

What was wrong with my attempt? If I can get this example to work, I should be able to apply it to my actual, more complicated problem, so any *good ideas* would be welcome.

Answer (score 7):

It looks to me like `NDEigensystem` is struggling with the singularity at $\zeta=1$, as does the method that I'm going to show. But perhaps it'll be useful for you, at least as a cross-check.

I have a package for numerically calculating solutions of eigenvalue problems using the Evans function via the method of compound matrices, which is [hosted on github](https://github.com/SPPearce/CompoundMatrixMethod). See my [answers to other questions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=compoundmatrixmethod), the example notebook on the github or [this introduction](https://www.maths.gla.ac.uk/~xl/FYB-background.pdf) for some more details.

First we install the package (only need to do this the first time):

```
Needs["PacletManager`"]
PacletInstall["CompoundMatrixMethod", 
    "Site" -> "http://raw.githubusercontent.com/paclets/Repository/master"]
```

Then we first need to turn the ODEs into a matrix form $\mathbf{y}'=\mathbf{A} \cdot \mathbf{y}$, using my function `ToMatrixSystem`:

```
Needs["CompoundMatrixMethod`"]
m = 3; q = 4/3;
op = -(1 - ζ^2) u''[ζ] + ζ u'[ζ] + 2 q (2 ζ^2 - 1) u[ζ];
sys[ζend_] = ToMatrixSystem[op == a u[ζ], {u[0] == 0, u[ζend] == 0}, u, {ζ, 0, ζend}, a]
```

Now the function Evans will calculate the Evans function (also known as the Miss-Distance function) for any given value of $a$ and $\zeta_{end}$; this is an analytic function whose roots coincide with eigenvalues of the original equation.

Plugging in $\zeta_{end} = 1$ fails due to the singularity, but you can try moving the endpoint slightly away:

```
FindRoot[Evans[a, sys[1 - 10^-3]], {a, 3}]
(* {a -> 4.00335} *)
```

Moving the endpoint closer approaches the correct value, but I can't get the exact value with this method.

```
aEvans = a /. FindRoot[Evans[a, sys[1 - 10^-10], WorkingPrecision -> 30], {a, 3}, 
  WorkingPrecision -> 30] // Quiet
(* {a -> 3.85301} *)
```

My package can't get the eigenfunctions directly at the moment, but you can use this eigenvalue in NDSolve (with an arbitrary second condition at $\zeta=0$, set it to be 2.45446 to make it consistent with the MathieuS):

```
sol = NDSolveValue[{op == aEvans u[\[Zeta]], {u[0] == 0, u'[0] == 1}},
   u, {\[Zeta], 0, 1 - 10^-10}];
Plot[{sol[\[Zeta]], flt[[1]][\[Zeta]]}, {\[Zeta], 0, 1 - 10^-10}]
```

[image]

The same should work for the other roots.

Answer (score 6):

If you refine the mesh, you will get closer:

```
m = 3; q = 4/3;
op = -(1 - \[Zeta]^2) u''[\[Zeta]] + \[Zeta] u'[\[Zeta]] + 
   2 q (2 \[Zeta]^2 - 1) u[\[Zeta]];
bc = DirichletCondition[u[\[Zeta]] == 0, True];
{\[Lambda], fl} = 
  NDEigensystem[{op, bc}, u, {\[Zeta], 0, 1}, m, 
   Method -> {"PDEDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", {"MeshOptions" \
-> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.00001}}}}];

\[Lambda]
{3.855, 16.074, 36.064}

\[Lambda]t = Table[MathieuCharacteristicB[2 k, q], {k, m}];
flt = Table[
   With[{j = j}, 
    MathieuS[MathieuCharacteristicB[2 k, q], q, ArcCos[#]] &], {k, m}];

\[Lambda]t // N
{3.852, 16.058, 36.025}
```